# Using instance names in loops C#

Tags: c#

I have instance names of Button objects: `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3`
,and I want to use one of these instance names in a loop like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
 {
   btn[j].someMethod();
 }
```

How can I do it in C#?

Comment: winforms, wpf, asp.net ?

Comment: Those are *variable* names - instances themselves don't have names. And basically, you should have a collection (e.g. an array or a list) instead of several separate variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put them into an array. For example

```
var buttons = new Button[] {btn1, btn2, btn3};
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
      button.SomeMethod();
}
```

By the way, in C# the convention is to use capital letter in the beginning of a method name.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke an object by its "reference object name" but that is not possible. 
To make your code work as desired you have to instantiate a Button array or list called btn and then loop through it as you prefer (for/for each).

Hope it helps,
Alessandro